# PHPUnit + Symfony does nothing

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I just installed PHPUnit on OS X + MAMP. (My phpunit was installed in my MAMP folder, so I copied it to /usr/bin because I couldn't use the "phpunit" command in terminal without the path)

#### New Symfony folder

When I go to a new Symfony2 folder and I try `phpunit -c App/`the tests start and I get a green confirmation that all tests passed.

```
PHPUnit 3.7.8 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from     
/Users/username/Dropbox/www/symfonydev/Symfony/App/phpunit.xml.dist
.
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 15.50Mb
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

#### Own symfony website

But when I go to my own little Symfony2 project and execute the same command, **nothing happens! He doesn't even load the phpunit.xml.dist**. I get no output at all on my terminal window.

**The test file, however, does exist and is readable, I can start it by explicitly specifying it on the command line of phpunit:**

`phpunit -c app/ src/MatchTracker/Bundle/Tests/Controller/AuthenticationControllerTest.php`and this works.

It seems that something is wrong with the phpunit.xml.dist. It's the default phpunit.xml.dist and I tried renaming it to phpunit.xml. But nothing happens. What could be the problem? I think he can't find my xml or use it, or maybe he can read the phpunit.xml but doesn't find my tests.

Here's an **example from my terminal**: You see that the phpunit command doesn't do anything, except when I specify the test file...

```
MacBook-Pro:www username$ ls
LICENSE     app     composer.json   composer.lock   composer.phar   src     vendor      web
MacBook-Pro:www username$ ls app/
AppCache.php        SymfonyRequirements.php cache           console         phpunit.xml.dist
AppKernel.php       autoload.php        check.php       logs
Resources       bootstrap.php.cache config          phpunit.xml
MacBook-Pro:www username$ phpunit -c app/
MacBook-Pro:www username$ phpunit -c app/ src/MatchTracker/Bundle/Tests/Controller/AuthenticationControllerTest.php
PHPUnit 3.7.8 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Users/username/Dropbox/www/matchtracker.be/www/app/phpunit.xml

F

Time: 1 second, Memory: 21.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) MatchTracker\Bundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex
Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 200.

/Users/username/Dropbox/www/matchtracker.be/www/src/MatchTracker/Bundle/Tests/Controller/AuthenticationControllerTest.php:28

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
MacBook-Pro:www username$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's in your `phpunit.xml`? `&lt;testsuites&gt;` section of this file tells phpunit which directories scan for tests.

Remember that `phpunit.xml` overwrites `phpunit.xml.dist`.

Look at the original [phpunit.xml.dist](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/phpunit.xml.dist) file and either remove the `phpunit.xml` or start by copying `phpunit.xml.dist` into `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: Yes, first I tried executing `phpunit -c app/`with only the default phpunit.xml.dist located in the app folder. But phpunit gives me no output. Then I copied everything to a phpunit.xml file. It should work with the default settings right? Here's my current [phpunit.xml](http://pastebin.com/qGVHn67i) but it's just the default values. They use wildcards, so my `src/MatchTracker/Bundle/Tests`should run? I have a defaultControllerTest and an authenticationControllerTest inside that folder.

Comment: I have my code on a [Github Repository](https://github.com/jessedobbelaere/MatchTracker) in case someone has an idea.

Comment: Your bundle doesn't follow naming conventions. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name

Comment: I see, thank you. I'd like to have only one bundle for my website, so a good name would be "src/MatchTracker/Bundle/AppBundle" then?

Comment: Sounds good to me :) Alternative might be src/MatchTracker/Bundle/<InsertYourProjectName>Bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also copied our code from the old bundle to the new renamed bundle structure inside a new Symfony installation and PHPUnit is running the default test now! Now I can finally try to do some test-driven development :)